# sql query - IF EXIST in WHERE clause

Tags: mysql, sql, select, join, where-clause

I have a query as like

```
SELECT * 
FROM aTable
LEFT JOIN aTableTranslate
ON aTable.id = aTableTranslate.aTable_id
WHERE
 aTableTransalte.language like 'en'
```

question is ....

is there any way to filter as like

...

```
WHERE
 aTableTranslate.language like (IF EXIST_A_FIELD_FOR 'en' THEN 'en' ELSE IF EXIST_A_FIELD_FOR 'jp' THEN 'jp' OR 'cn')
```

?

I want to show list with 1. visitor's language > 2. english ... > or default language.

is it possible by query?

Comment: yes - create an applicable where clause....

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/control-flow-functions.html#function_if

Comment: What does this `EXIST_A_FIELD_FOR` means?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could join to translation tables separately, and pick the first non-`NULL` translation with [`COALESCE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#function_coalesce), like this:

```
SELECT a.*, COALESCE(t1.translation, t2.translation, t3.translation) as translation
FROM aTable a
LEFT JOIN aTableTranslate t1 ON aTable.id = t1.aTable_id AND t1.language like 'en'
LEFT JOIN aTableTranslate t2 ON aTable.id = t2.aTable_id AND t2.language like 'jp'
LEFT JOIN aTableTranslate t3 ON aTable.id = t3.aTable_id AND t3.language like 'cn'
```

Comment: Thnks. You exactly answered what I want to know. Thanks.

Comment: is there any way to use as COALESCE(t1.*, t2.*, t3.*) ?

Comment: @user2660234 Unfortunately, `COALESCE` cannot be used with asterisks: it produces a single column in the output, so you would need one `COALESCE` for each column of the translation table.

Comment: thanks again. I want somebody who is making db server to add function to retrieve whole columns on COALESCE. Anyway now I write huge many COALESCEs. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT a.*, COALESCE(IF(t1.language = 'en', t1.translation, NULL), 
                     IF(t1.language = 'jp', t1.translation, NULL), 
                     IF(t1.language = 'cn', t1.translation, NULL)
                   ) AS translation
FROM aTable a
LEFT JOIN aTableTranslate t1 ON aTable.id = t1.aTable_id AND t1.language IN ('en', 'jp', 'cn')
```